# mongoDB api endpoint

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB to store data for my users and trying to create an api/users endpoint for the post method however everytime I post the form its giving me 404 api/users can't be found. How can I make the endpoint properly? been trying to follow a tutorial but the code just says app.post('api/db') but that's giving me 404, where's the api/ coming from?

my db collection looks like

```
movDB -- DB
- users (collection)
-- email, pass (collection objs)
```

submit controller with post method

```
$http.post('api/users/', vm.newUser).success(function(response){

        }).error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
```

server.js app.post

```
app.post('api/users/', authController.signup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add '/' in your endpoint

```js
app.post('/api/users/', authController.signup);
```

Comment: what >.< just a missing forward slash.. I thought it'd be something more than :/. Thanks